# Carbocation Rearrangements in SN1 reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Would one get 1-(1-chloroethyl)-1-methylcyclobutane?

I am not sure if the driving force identification is correct? Is my going from a 2° to a 3° carbocation correct? Does anyone have any tips for knowing when to look out for rearrangements?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solvolysis would involve rearrangement to the cyclopentyl carbocation as indicated in the figure below.  The driving force for the rearrangement is two-fold

1. without rearrangement, the cyclobutyl compound would generate a secondary carbocation; with rearrangement a more stable tertiary carbocation is generated instead
2. release of strain as the 4-membered ring opens to a 5-membered ring

[image]

The tertiary cyclopentyl carbocation ultimately captures a solvent molecule as indicated.

Comment: the + charge goes onto the cyclic ring. Does that destabilize the ring more than having a 4-membered ring?

Comment: An $\ce{sp^2}$ carbon would like to be around 120 degrees; that angle is not destabilizing in 5-membered or larger rings.